# Replace Markdown-like links with HTML links in a string

Tags: php

I have a strings of the form

```
"Look at this [website]{http://www.stackoverflow.com} 
or at this [page]{http://www.google.com}"
```

and I want to parse them with PHP to

```
"Look at this <a href='http://wwwstackoverflow.com'>website</a> 
or at this <a href='http://www.google.com'>page</a>"
```

How can I do this?

I though about using `str_replace()`but I dont know how to get the string between the brackets `[]`.

**Edit[26.08.2016]**: The answer uses the PHP preg_replace method with *Regular Expression*. I didnt understand the given answer here, but it worked so I was happy But now I found [this](https://regexone.com/) free tutorial that teaches you how to use Regular Expression. I found it very helpful. Especially when one wants to wrtie his own Regular Expression for a similar case.

Comment: Use [this](http://parsedown.org/). Don't reinvent the wheel. **Note:** the syntax is slightly different for links.

Comment: @Script47: This isn't *quite* markdown syntax.  Links are `[Title](http://example.com)`.  He'd have to replace the `{}` with `()` to use that.

Comment: @Script47 Unfortunately it's not *quite* Markdown. Adam, how about you actually *do* use an existing markup language?

Comment: With regex and `preg_replace`, I guess

Comment: @Rocket LOL. Even the emphasis was the same...

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yep, just saw. Thanks. I'll leave it there with a note saying it is slightly different.

Comment: @deceze: I was reading your mind!

Comment: @Script47 okay thank you for the link. I do not really mind to replace {} by (). However, if there would be  a more simple solution then using a plugin, I would definitely prefer it.

Comment: @Adam You aren't going to get a simpler solution than "Include this piece of code, call this function". Far more complicated would be trying to parse the text on your own; it's way easier to just use Markdown and be done with it

Comment: @QPaysTaxes with more simple, I meant less code. If I need to do more replacing things I will of course consider using the library. But since I only need to cover this single case, I find it more natural to use once a preg_replace command than including a plugin.

Comment: @Adam That library would be a couple lines of code, and you wouldn't have to worry about finding and fixing edge cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try it with `preg_replace`

```
$str="Look at this [website]{http://www.stackoverflow.com} or at this [page]{http://www.google.com}";

echo preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\{(.*?)\}/', "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $str);
```

output:

```
Look at this <a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>website</a> or at this <a href='http://www.google.com'>page</a>
```

working Example: https://3v4l.org/jLbff

Answer (score 1):

This can be made easily by using `preg_replace`:

```
$pattern = "/(\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\{([^\\}]+)\\})/";
$replacement = '<a href="$3">$2</a>';
$finalStr = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $yourString);
```