# Javascript regex exec equivalent in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have this function:

```
function fixLinks(str){
    var newStr = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/g, function(text){
        let [fullmatch, name, link] = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g.exec(text)
        return `<a href="${link}">${name}</a>`
    });

    return newStr;
}
```

which takes a string with markdown-like links, and wraps them in an href.

I want to do the same with PHP, but I don't know an equivalent to the "exec" method of the regex.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `preg_match`, or here, just use `preg_replace` with capturing groups in the pattern and backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Thing is, I'm not really sure how it works in the JS version, I just need to get it working, I'll try preg_replace and see if I can make it work, thx!

Comment: The JS code is too redundant, it uses a callable where a mere string replacement pattern would work.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I could get it to work using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078367/replace-markdown-like-links-with-html-links-in-a-string